# Preventing iframe busting kills all links on site

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have this script below, which does prevent an iFrame from busting out, but it also kills every link on my page. How do I prevent the script from disabling all my links?

```
<script>
    var prevent_bust = 0  
    window.onbeforeunload = function() { prevent_bust++ }  
    setInterval(function() {  
        if (prevent_bust > 0) {  
            prevent_bust -= 2  
            // 204 header response prevents redirect
            window.top.location = '/204-response'  
        }  
    }, 1)  
</script>
```

The issue I have is exactly as described here: http://slightlyparanoid.com/?p=11

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Is there a reason you're using this approach to framebust? The generally accepted approach is to compare `self === top`, which I highly doubt would break any anchor tags:

```
if (self !== top) {
    // this script is running in an iframe
} else {
    // this script is not running in an iframe
}
```

This will most likely on affect IE ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

- Click an anchor that refers to another document.
- Invoke the anchor.click method.

To allow the `onbeforeunload` event from continuing without interfering with anchor tag clicks, you have to return `undefined` from it.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
    prevent_bust++; 
    return undefined; 
};
```

To clarify, `onbeforeunload` is expecting a string to return from the handler, which it will then throw in a confirm box. If you return `undefined`, it bypasses this and just continues with the `unload` event.

Comment: This is happening in FF and Chrome as well, and `return undefined` doesn't seem to be fixing it. The script appears to prevent any link from working, not just the redirection in the iframe.

Comment: The purpose is to prevent framebusting... How would I use `self===top` to prevent an iframe from busting out?

Answer (score 0):

As of right now the best method to disable frame busting is [sandbox](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) but as you may find in your testing
this approach has some drawbacks.

However, the 204 code disables all browser navigation (all links, back, forward, etc).
Some browsers, however,
have re-instated the back and forward buttons, but still no link navigation, so applying this to your code maybe isn't the best Idea, have you tried adding the '/204-response' to the
Iframes source (src attribute)?

Frame busting is kind of an issue here with cross-origin embedding... But like I said the sandbox rule only works to an extent.

So give the sandbox attribute a go, and let us know how it works!
(obviously, this type of thing is specific to each case, but this is a good general approach.)